# IMC Calculator with switch

Tags: javascript

```
I was working in a IMC calculator to exercise js. This calculator should shows the IMC and a message acording the result but, for some reason, it always shows the default message.

    

const form = document.querySelector('#form');
    
    
    form.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();

    const weight = document.querySelector('#weight').value;
    const height = document.querySelector('#height').value;

    const bmi = (weight / (height **2)).toFixed(2);


    const value = document.querySelector('#value');
    let description = '';

    document.querySelector('#infos').classList.remove('hiden');

    
    switch(bmi){
        case bmi < 18.5:
            description = 'Cuidado! Você está abaixo do peso!';
            break;
        case bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 25:
            description = "Você está no peso ideal!";
            value.classList.remove('attention');
            value.classList.add('normal');
            break;
        case bmi > 25 && bmi <= 30:
            description = "Cuidado! Você está com sobrepeso!";
            break;
        case bmi > 30 && bmi <= 35:
            description = "Cuidado! Você está com obesidade moderada!";
            break;
        case bmi > 35 && bmi <= 40:
            description = "Cuidado! Você está com obesidade severa!";
            break;
        case bmi > 40:
            description = "Cuidado! Você está com obesidade morbida!";
            break;
        default:
            description = "verifique novamente";
            break;
        }
    value.textContent = bmi.replace('.', ',')
    document.querySelector('#description').textContent =description ;
   
});
```

I've tried to rewrite, use parentheses in case conditions like this > case (bmi > 25 && bmi <= 30) and checked the homework instructions. Algo seak in yt looking for some tutorial using switch, but didn't found any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are switching on a number but the cases all evaluate to booleans, so they can ever match. You could instead use a series of `if`, `else if`, and `else`.

Alternatively, switch on `true` instead, which will cause the first case that evaluates to `true` to be chosen.

```js
switch (true) {
    // ...
}
```